# Sidebar in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, sidebar

How to crete the collapsible Sidebar menu in ASP.NET MVC [Like this image, How to create the sidebar menu in ASP.NEt MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZpn4.png)

I'm not getting the exact procudure to create the sidemenu bar.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to create a container div and make this div sticky, so that div will stay fixed while the page is innervated. Then you can create a list like this by giving the dive flex and using the flex properties to list the links in the div.